# Receiving emails that my Microsoft azure student account's credits will expire even though it hasn't been 12 months

Tags: azure, credits

I have an issue with my Microsoft azure student account's credits. I get emails claiming that the credits of my account will run out in a couple of days even though, It's been under a month since I initially signed up. As the free trial states that I have 12 months free.

Comment: Hi AFB, and welcome to StackOverflow. This type of question would be better asked to Microsoft Azure's support team, as it's off-topic for StackOverflow. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

If this is with regards to the [Azure for Students Starter](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/students/) offer, you may open a [Support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/) with us so our Team can assist you further. Thanks.